# How to update Redux state, using ng-model?

Tags: angularjs, redux

I have this HTML:

```
<input ng-model="state.input.name">
<input ng-model="state.input.password">
```

I have a Redux store. I want that every time that the user type into the box, instead of only  change the value in Angular way, I want to run update store Redux state:

Something like this:

```
store.setState(_.extend({},store.getState(),{input:state.input})
```

I can do it using `ng-change`, the point is I want it to work automatically for any `ng-model`.  I also want the the value of `state.input.name` will got from state. For read only elements it is not problem:

```
<div ng-bind="{{store.getState().input.name}}">
```

But for read/write, I cannot auto-connect it to store.

I thought maybe to intercepter the `Angular.apply` * `Angular.dispatch` methods or create a `ng-model` directive that adds this functionality.

Comment: I have tried to use redux as a transactional container. I update the container only after the user click on a "save" button, for example. But I understand what you need.

Answer (score 0):

I found a very simple way to do that, by using Angular `watch` method:

```
$rootScope.watch('state.input',function(){
    store.setState({input:$rootScope.state})
)
```